# How to change active mobile menu item color?

Tags: css

I'm trying to change the active mobile menu item color, and have used this code I found online but it's not working.

```
    .nav-menu a {
    color: #fff !important;
}
.nav-menu a:hover {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

The website is: [roheatingandcooling.com](https://roheatingandcooling.com/)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Did I not explain the issue and provide code I'm having an issue with?

Comment: You did not. Read [mcve]. You posted two CSS rules. We need a complete example in your question.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some confusion here. `Hover` refers to styling applied to element while the mouse pointer is hovering above it. `Active` refers to styling the element while it is on an "activated" state, regardless of where the mouse pointer is. E.g. button is pressed.

You wrote "active" on your question but your code says "hover".

To target the active state use:

```
.nav-menu a:active {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

More info on the [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp).

Comment: Hey there william! I tried to apply this on my website, but it didn't work unfortunately.